# adding values of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to add the score of individual players and want to display the most runs scored by the player. This is the example of dictionaries that i am referring:

```
{'match1': {'player1': 57, 'player2': 38},
 'match2': {'player3': 9, 'player1': 42},
 'match3': {'player2': 41, 'player4': 63, 'player3': 91}}
```

I tried many solutions but unable to make a logic so that it will add the scores of individual players from different matches. Any help will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Post your solution and explain what's wrong with it. Also, please show the output you wanna get.

Comment: You may be interested in `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the sum of values within the values of a nested Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000681/find-the-sum-of-values-within-the-values-of-a-nested-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the nested `dictionary` and add up scores to a dictionary of player totals.

```
def find_totals(d):
    total = {}
    for match, results in d.items():
        for player, score in results.items():
            total[player] = total.get(player, 0) + score
    return total
```

**Sample Output**

```
>>> d = {'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}}
>>> print find_totals(d)
{'player2': 79, 'player3': 100, 'player1': 99, 'player4': 63}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def score(match):
    players = {}
    for key in match:
        for player in match[key]:
            if player not in players:
                players[player] =match[key][player]
            else:
                players[player]+=match[key][player]
    return players
```

Quick overview, if the player is not in the new dictionary, create the membership and point the key to the score of that player. Else add the score to the total of that player

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem,

```
d = {'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}}
players = {}
for key, val in enumerate(d):
    #print val
    for ele,value in enumerate(d[val]):
        #print value
        if value not in players:
            players[value] = d[val][value]
        else:
            players[value] += d[val][value]

print players
highest = 0
highest_player = ""
for key, value in enumerate(players):
    if players[value]>highest:
        highest = players[value]
        highest_player = highest_player.replace(highest_player, value)
print highest_player,players[highest_player]
```

Hope this helps you.